# How to have different servers have unique variables. Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a bot that keeps track of when someone performs the f bomb. I want to have a variable that is unique for each of the servers the bot is in that keeps track of how many f bombs someone has made since the bot entered the server. However I don't have any clue on how to do any of this. Therefore I don't have any meaningful code to show besides this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token  = 'garbage';

var f_bombs = 0; //except I want one of these variables for each server it is on so server 1 can have 2 f bombs total and server 2 can have 1034 f bombs.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having right now is with your [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp). You should make your scope local for each guild. I would do this with a promise like so:

```
const fBombs = {}
fBombs[message.guild.id] = 0
fBombs[message.guild.id]++
```

Comment: It says that 'message' is undefined.

Comment: You need to make sure that you are adding that in your message event. ```bot.on('message', async message => {
//paste here
})```

Comment: But then how do I set fBombs to 0 if its going to be set to zero everytime some types in a message.

Comment: check and see if it exists, `if (!fBombs[message.guild.id]) fBombs[message.guild.id] = 0`

Comment: Yes this worked perfectly. Thanks for basically making my bot!